# How do I solve an error in my React Button Component?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, react-props

I have an error in my Button component but I don't know what is wrong. It would be great if somebody can help me...
The code is below. Recently I added ESLint + Prettier but I don't know if that's the problem.

■Exported file

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Button.module.css';

const Button = (props) => {
return (
<button
  type={props.type}
  className={`${classes.button} ${props.className}`}
  onClick={props.onClick}
>
  {props.children}
</button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

■Imported file

```
import Button from '../UI/Button';

const Login = () => {
return (
<div>
  <form>
    <Button
      type='submit'
      className={classes['login-btn']}
      onClick={submitLoginHandler}
    >
      Login
    </Button>
  </form>
</div>
);
};

export default Login;
```

■Error
[image]

Comment: You are missing PropTypes for Button component, please take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: @noumanniazi Defining propTypes isn't mandatory.

Comment: Do you have defined propTypes for your `Button` component where you made some of them required and use the `Button` somewhere and not pass some props?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are warning not error. Its say you must check your prop type (String,İnt,Bool,Func)

For your code:

```
Button.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  className:PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  children: PropTypes.string
};
```

But I recommend you to not use children prop use for example use buttonLabel.

```
<Button
  type='submit'
  className={classes['login-btn']}
  onClick={submitLoginHandler}
  buttonLabel="Login"
  />
```

And get props like this :

```
const Button = ({type,className,onClick,buttonLabel}) => {
return (
<button
  type={type}
  className={`${classes.button} ${className}`}
  onClick={onClick}
>
  {buttonLabel}
</button>
  );
};
```

Final Proptypes:

```
Button.propTypes = {
  type: PropTypes.string,
  className:PropTypes.string,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  buttonLabel: PropTypes.string
};
```

More info :
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.htm

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to React and haven't encountered PropTypes yet. I Will read the document you posted for sure!